# Why does my opengl freeglut application compile as C but not as C++?

Tags: c++, c

It isn't a problem with the code because it compiles when I tell the compiler to compile it as C but it doesn't compile when I set the settings to default (which is to compile it as C++). When I compile it as C++ I get numerous errors along the lines of "undefined reference to glClear"

I'm using Microsoft's Visual Studio C++ compiler. I have everything properly linked.

The code is:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>



void display(void)
{
    /* Clear all pixels */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    /*  draw white polygon (rectangle) with
     *  corners at (0.25, 0.25, 0.0) and (0.75, 0.75, 0.0)
     */

    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(0.25, 0.25, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.75, 0.25, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.75, 0.75, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.25, 0.75, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    /*  don't wait!
     *  start processing buffered OpenGL routines
     */

        glFlush();
}

void init(void)
{
    /* Select clearing background color */
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    /* Initialize viewing values */
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}


/*
* Declare initial window size, position, and display mode
* (single buffer and RGBA). Open window with “hello”
* in its title bar. Call initialization routines.
* Register callback function to display graphics.
* Enter main loop and process events.
*/
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(250, 250);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("hello");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0; /* ISO C requires main to return int. */
}
```

Also, if anyone has a proper resource for learning opengl with C++ could you please recommend it?

Comment: What is the exact error? Is it a compile error or a link error?

Comment: I get an error that says, 
undefined reference to gl<insertfunctionhere>

I know I have everything properly linked because when I compile it in C it works

Comment: *undefined reference* is a linker error. Are you including opengl32.lib?

Comment: Put the exact errors in your question.

Comment: It is a linker error, the errors are basically all undefined reference to gl<insertfunctionhere>, I don't know why it doesn't work but I dont think you guys can help, sorry for wasting your time

Comment: So then you're not linking properly, even though you say you are. Verify that first.

Comment: Try putting `extern "C" { ... }`around your includes.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely because `glClear` is not declared in any of the header files currently included.  In C, an undeclared function is often assumed to have a certain type based on its arguments, and returning an `int`.  So when compiling with C, you might get a warning about it being undeclared (I hopefully you have warnings enabled, and read them when compiling?), but it will do its best to compile and link it.

C++ is more strict about undeclared functions.

Answer (score 1):

As Alexadre Jasmin and Bart have pointed out, verify that you are linking OpenGL libraries correctly. I use

```
-lGLU -lGL -lglut
```

with freeglut on ubuntu.

If that doesn't solve the problem, try adding

```
#define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK
```

at the top of your cpp file.